# Getting high Error% in jmeter after run, how to know this error is due what (machine config issue, request issue..)

Tags: jmeter

Getting high Error% in jmeter after run, how to know this error is due to out of memory or used machine doesn't have capability or the http request has an issue. In my case getting Error% in jmeter summary report is 97.50% (for login api) and when loaded this result in 'View results tree' can see 500 internal server errors or the failed requests. Please suggest what measures can be taken to analyse these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1)

> **10.5 Server Error 5xx**
>
> Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.
>
> **10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

So the possible reasons are in:

1. You are sending incorrect requests which cannot be processed on your server side. Check server logs for details, most probably you will be able to figure out something from them. If you don't have access to logs you can at least configure JMeter to save response data for failed requests, add the following lines to *user.properties* file to trigger this on:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```

   Check out [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) chapter for more information.
2. It may be your application components configuration which is not suitable for high loads, i.e. your application server or database can be configured to accept not more than X connections and your load test is exceeding this value. The solution is again to check application, web server and database logs and make required configuration changes
3. It may be due to simple lack of resources, i.e. CPU or RAM on server side so you can monitor them using u.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for more details.